# Where can I get the works of Jayatirtha and Vyasatirtha in English translation?

Tags: philosophy, vedanta, translation-request, dvaita

Jayatirtha and Vyasatirtha, two extremely brilliant philosophers of Vedanta, have been characterized by countless scholars both from the East and West as presenting "the highest dialectical skill in the whole of Indian thought". It is therefore a great matter of shame and sadness that their works are not to be found anywhere in English translation.

I am specifically interested in the Nyayasudha of Jayatirtha which was translated in three volumes by BNK Sharma but so far I have not been able to find these online. They were present on archive.org for a while but apparently someone deleted them at one point.

It would be greatly appreciated if any work of either Jayatirtha or Vyasatirtha which is available anywhere in English online be given here. They should be made available in PDF. Specifically, greater interest should be paid to the Nyayasudha of Jayatirtha and the Nyayamrota of Vyasatirtha or anything else by them. The more works are made available, the better.

Comment: Are you looking for free translations (paid one is [here](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/nyaya-sudha-of-sri-jayatirtha-first-adhyayas-complete-NAN434/))? 'They should be made available in PDF' - is this a demand? What if the translation is copyrighted? 'They were present on archive.org for a while but apparently someone deleted them at one point' - the most likely reason they were taken down is due to copyright violation.

Comment: You could also get it here http://www.gyanasampat.in/tsraghavendran/

Comment: @PrasannaR: I can't find any english translation (ebook) on that site relating to either Jayatirtha or Vyasatirtha.

Comment: I don't have ebook Please check https:jnyana.org this person had digitized all old original manuscript and preserved in RIT Vedic library but I don't have any other link, may be you need to purchase hardcopy only